# ElasticSearch - search filter not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I have bulked insert 1000 car records into ElasticSearch.

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "car", "_type" : "car", "_id" : "1" } }
{"id":1,"car_make":"Chevrolet","car_model":"Express","car_year":2012,"car_color":"Goldenrod","made_in":"Indonesia"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "car", "_type" : "car", "_id" : "2" } }
{"id":2,"car_make":"BMW","car_model":"Z8","car_year":2002,"car_color":"Fuscia","made_in":"China"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "car", "_type" : "car", "_id" : "3" } }
...
...
...
```

When I run the following, I was expecting to get some result back, but now I'm getting zero results.

```
>> curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/car/car/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
> {
>   "query": {
>     "bool": {
>       "must": { "match_all": {} },
>       "filter": {
>         "terms": {
>           "car_make": ["BMW","Lexus"]
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> 
> '
{
  "took" : 18,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you share your mappings of `car_make` ?

Comment: can you share the mapping for the index?

Answer (score 0):

Do you create a custom mapping for the `car` (index/type)? If not, it will be defaulted to `text` with `keyword` fields type (if you using es 5.x can't remember exact version).

If that the case, you can try:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "car_make.keyword": ["BMW","Lexus"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```